# How can I get username from Window Authentication, in GWT-RPC application?

Tags: java, gwt, authentication, windows-authentication, gwt-rpc

As the question say, can I get Windows Username in a GWT-RPC application?

**Edit** : NOTE: `System.getProperty("user.name");`  throws error in GWT-RPC

`The method getProperty(String) is undefined for the type System`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.getProperty("user.name");` that will return the username.

**EDIT** : What I found is [Apache waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/). WAFFLE - Windows Authentication Functional Framework (Light Edition) is a native C# and Java library that does everything Windows authentication (Negotiate, NTLM and Kerberos).

[This](http://code.dblock.org/tomcat-single-sign-on-mixed-with-form-authentication-w-waffle) is one of the example which matches your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Is there any way so that I can ask the user to enter his credentials again when accessing my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can get windows user name by

```
String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

Then you can wrap it in your GWT-RPC app.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Is there any way so that I can ask the user to enter his credentials again when accessing my application?

Comment: could you elaborate? you can always display a pop-up/page/dialog.

Comment: Ok these is an intranet application, as long as the user is trying to access the application from a machine that he’s logged in with an account that belongs to a particular group, it should let him in. If the account is not authorized, a message should be shown asking him to contact administrator. Sorry the complete question has been changed now.

Comment: so the backend authentication server is ActiveDirectory? or what?

Comment: Please have a look at this,. http://mhimu.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/active-directory-authentication-using-javajndi/